# Prevent tmux from consuming escape key

Tags: tmux

For some reason tmux is consuming/handling the escape key weird.

When in tmux, if I hit enter nothing is sent. If I quickly double press escape, then two escape keys will be sent. I can also press escape followed by any other key and it will enter the escape followed by the key.

I read a few posts suggesting to add `set -g escape-time 0`, but this has the wrong effect. This basically means I would have to double press within 0ms (impossible), making it impossible to hit escape at all.

Is there any way to just let tmux not handle the escape key at all and behave normally? It makes vim really hard to use.

Comment: Did setting `set -sg escape-time 0` change anything? If not, please post your `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: My tmux config is pretty long, so I decided to test it with the default config to see if the issue was my config or not (not sure why I didnt think of that before -- thanks!). Turns out, it was, so I slowly tested more and more of my config until it broke and finally found the culprit. I had a binding to `C-[`. I am not exactly sure how this interaction works, but if you `cat` and press escape you get `^[` so kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by adding a keybinding to `C-[`. I have not found any way to use this key binding without conflicting with escape, so I think they best answer is to avoid using this binding.

Comment: It is unfortunate, but the root of this issue is that the escape key is literally sent not as its own key, but as `C-[`. When you strike `C-[`, there is no feasible way for the terminal to determine if that was Escape or `C-[`; they are the same