# NeoVim sluggish with tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, neovim

## NeoVim use 0.5-1 sec to go from insert to normal mode IF in tmux, not otherwise.

I use Alacritty with WSL (Debian), and have tested in the following ways.

### Tested if it was NeoVim plugins

NeoVim started with no plugins: `nvim -u NONE`

### Use settings to lessen load on tmux / config tmux for performance

Some options I saw could possibly slow down tmux;

```
set -g mouse off
set -g status-interval 60
set-option -g history-limit 10000
```

### Used several terminal emulators to test it was not the emulator or WSL

Used PowerShell, Git Bash and Alacritty, without tmux.

### Results

I combined these, so I used a performant tmux config, with several emulators, all in WSL, with a no-plugin NeoVim, and the only time it was sluggish to go from insert to normal mode was when I used tmux. I thought maybe it is because tmux is using the escape key, but I use `Ctrl+Space` and not what was talked about here: https://superuser.com/a/1343036/1763274

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to tmux using escape as a command prefix, and I fixed the issue by simply adding this to my `.tmux.config`;

`set -sg escape-time 10`

Makes it wait for 10ms after you press escape before it handles it like a normal escape keypress (I think). At least it works to fix the issue for me.